# is their any industry standard for performing 300K load test (Thermostat->HVAC system)?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, aws-ec2-instance-connect, azure-load-testing

We need to perform 300K Thermostat load test. all 300K thermostats was connected to **different 300K IPs** via WIFI connection.

**Client machines**: AWS EC2 instances/Azure load testing service.
**Server machine**: Here we can observe the **Azure VMSS** metrics like CPU,Memory and so on....

is their any industry standard for performing this requirement?

We used AWS EC2 instances for doing this requirement.

Each AWS EC2 Instance we are running 8000 Thermostats.Single AWS EC2 (IP) we are connected 8000 Thermostats (Thats not exact reliastic).

We need to use 300K AWS EC2 instances for performing this load test? (or) ony other easy way to achieve this requirement (azure load test) and so on?

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler there is "Source IP" field where you can specify the IP address (or alias) to bind to:

[image]

The IP address or alias must be present in the operating system.

More information: [IP Spoofing With JMeter: How to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ip-spoofing-jmeter)

Comment: how many ips can we spoof in a single AWS EC2 VM? I can see some blog it shows only maximum  of 100 ip spoofing can be done in a sigle cloud vm? if that was the case still we need more machines (3000) for performing 300K load test. Is their any other approach to perform this requrement?